# Как узнать размер папки в Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10

Это наверное самый глупый вопрос на этой платформе, но всё же:
как узнать реальный размер папки, который она занимает на диске?
Потому что Проводник, показывает не правильный размер.

Comment: Открыть свойства папки.

Comment: А что значит неправильный? Какой по-вашему правильный?

Comment: давняя проблема windows 10. обратите внимание на количество комментариев: https://answers.microsoft.com/ru-ru/windows/forum/windows_10-files/%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB/c78f2b6b-7770-46e0-b89c-fa2e380fcef0

Comment: > Это наверное самый глупый вопрос на этой платформе.. Нет, напротив проблема размера папки стара как Windows 10 и до сей поры не решена (см. картинку; размер всего диска - 2Тбайт) [![проводник](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o38L.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3o38L.png) Что делать не знаю. Наверное, ждать выхода Windows12

Answer (score 1):

Программа Disk Usage v1.61
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/du

Попробуйте это, размер показывается в байтах

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/343122)

Comment: Это ссылка на скачивание программы и вряд ли будет изменена ссылка с docs.microsoft

Comment: @ClarkDevlin во-первых, Microsoft неоднократно был замечен за поломкой ссылок. Во-вторых, можно хотя бы название программы в ответ поместить, чтобы при поломке ссылки её можно было нагуглить

Answer (score 0):

Откройте свойства и там будет указан точный размер в скобочках